# Nextpeer Remove welcome banner : Delegate method not fired

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nextpeer

I tried to remove nextpeer welcome notification at game start.

Here is my code in .h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,NextpeerDelegate,NPTournamentDelegate,NPNotificationDelegate,..>
```

//in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)initializeNextpeer
{
    NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                              // This game has no retina support - therefore we have to let the platform know
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE], NextpeerSettingGameSupportsRetina,
                              // Support orientation change for the dashboard notifications
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], NextpeerSettingSupportsDashboardRotation,
                              // Support orientation change for the in game notifications
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE], NextpeerSettingObserveNotificationOrientationChange,
                              //  Place the in game notifications on the bottom screen (so the current score will be visible)
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:NPNotificationPosition_BOTTOM], NextpeerSettingNotificationPosition,
                              nil];



    [Nextpeer initializeWithProductKey:@"HERE ADDED GAME KEY" andSettings:settings andDelegates:
     [NPDelegatesContainer containerWithNextpeerDelegate:self notificationDelegate:[NPCocosNotifications sharedManager] tournamentDelegate:self]];


}
- (BOOL)nextpeerShouldShowWelcomeBanner {
    return NO; // Do not Show banner
}
```

Nextpeer working great. Only this function is not fired. What's wrong?

Comment: did you assign/register the appdelegate as delegate for nextpeer?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yes I added, nextpeerDashboardWillAppear  delegate call is fired but not nextpeerShouldShowWelcomeBanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextpeerShouldShowWelcomeBanner` is a method on the `NPNotificationDelegate`, not on `NextpeerDelegate`. In your code sample, the notification delegate is `[NPCocosNotifications sharedManager]`. So you should move the method to that object, or set a different notification delegate.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:* This no longer applies - it seems the current version of Nextpeer (1.7.4) doesn't support this.**

You need to add the method to whichever class is implementing the `NPNotificationDelegate` not `NextPeerDelegate`.

But the trouble is, the default `NPNotificationDelegate` is `NPCocosNotifications` - which is a class inside the Nextpeer library. So when you update the library, you need to also remember to make the same edit again to the new version of `NPCocosNotifications`.

But there's a neater way to do this using a category, which means you don't need to make the edit again when you update.

1)

Create this file: `NSObject+NPCocosNotification_NotShowWelcomeBanner.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NPCocosNotifications.h"

@interface NPCocosNotifications (NPCocosNotification_NotShowWelcomeBanner)

@end
```

Create this file: `NSObject+NPCocosNotification_NotShowWelcomeBanner.m`

```
#import "NSObject+NPCocosNotification_NotShowWelcomeBanner.h"

@implementation NPCocosNotifications (NPCocosNotification_NotShowWelcomeBanner)

- (BOOL)nextpeerShouldShowWelcomeBanner {
    return NO; // Do NOT show banner as the game starts up
}

@end
```

Drag those files into the project making sure the "Copy into destination group's folder (if needed)" is selected and "Add to target (your project's build target name)".

2)
Add this line to your app delegate and any other files which reference `NPCocosNotification`

```
// This adds a method to prevent the welcome banner showing
#import "NSObject+NPCocosNotification_NotShowWelcomeBanner.h"
```

The new method, to turn off the banner, will be added to `NPCocosNotifications` :)

Comment: thanks for your answer...for me Vladimir's solution worked before...now not tested...by seeing your answer I guess its again broken...thanks for this solution.

Comment: I hope it helps you (and others)! This is effectively the same solution as Vladimir Gritsenko gave but implemented in your application code instead of the Nextpeer library code. To be clear; Vladimir Gritsenko's answer will work just fine, but requires you to remember to redo it whenever you update Nextpeer :)